# react app not fully loaded after building with electron- builder

Tags: reactjs, electron, create-react-app, electron-builder

after building my app the app dosent load properly  : [image]
the app  should load a login page in the / path but it dosent i tried hosting the react app with netlify and it worked right but it dosent with electron
i used npm run electron:build
here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "security_cams_management_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Abderrahmane fatimi",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "pocketbase": "^0.13.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start \" \"npm run electron:start\"",
    "electron:build": "npm run build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
    "electron:start": "wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000 && electron ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^24.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "build":{
    "appId": "com.electron.security_cams_management_app",
    "productName" : "Store Managment App",
    "extends": null,
    "files":[
      "dist/**/*",
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my main.js file :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

const path = require('path')
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    minWidth: 1200,
    minHeight: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  })

  win.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
  )
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

and this is the files structure
[image]